# how do heavy traffic websites handle load using dns routing?

Tags: web-services, web

It says larger websites have their server distributed on several machines running the same website and depending on load a user is routed to one of the server machines . This happens without users knowledge and under same domain name as far as user's interface is concerned.

now the bit I don't get is even though you eliminate the bottleneck of using a single server by using distributed server how would you eliminate the bottleneck of dns.

It would require some kind of routing gateway that routes user to one of the servers for the Web page (resolving dns) now this gateway would be bombarded with requests.

So how would you reduce the routing gateway load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you'll use several DNS servers for the zone.  Even when you do that though, there are techniques to do this load balancing at the network layer.

Commonly referred to as "anycast", it's possible for multiple hosts to have the same IP address on the internet.  Normal internet routing can then be used to route users to a server on the best path.

For example, you could put DNS servers on all continents and assign them all the same address, `8.8.8.8`.  Users in Europe would most likely end up on the European DNS server.

There is quite a bit of investment and administrative overhead for this, which is one of the reasons why globally distributed DNS hosting providers charge a premium price for this feature.

Comment: "it's possible for multiple hosts to have the same IP address on the internet", Isn't that kind of breaking the principles of Networking? or is it something like NAT?

Comment: @Allahjane Actually no, it's using basic internet routing for what it's good for... routing.

If you had two hosts with the same IP address on the same broadcast domain (like in your home network), you'd definitely run into trouble.  But, if you had two hosts with the same IP address on two different broadcast domains and you didn't need them to talk to each other, there's no problem.  To routers on the internet, it just looks like there are (at least) two paths to the same network and one of them happens to be very short.

Comment: @Allahjane Other hosts on the internet don't have to know or care that there are duplicates.  They're only interested in connecting to one.

Comment: " To routers on the internet, it just looks like there are (at least) two paths to the same network and one of them happens to be very short"

That hits the spot!